# ARKit image detection, add image

Tags: swift, xcode, image, scenekit, arkit

I'm using ARKit 1.5 (beta) for image detection. Once I detect my image I would like to then place a AR scene image using the plane detected. How can this be done?

My code so far which detects the image (which is in my assets folder):

```
/// - Tag: ARImageAnchor-Visualizing
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
    updateQueue.async {

        // Create a plane to visualize the initial position of the detected image.
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                             height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.opacity = 0.25

        /*
         `SCNPlane` is vertically oriented in its local coordinate space, but
         `ARImageAnchor` assumes the image is horizontal in its local space, so
         rotate the plane to match.
         */
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        /*
         Image anchors are not tracked after initial detection, so create an
         animation that limits the duration for which the plane visualization appears.
         */
        planeNode.runAction(self.imageHighlightAction)

        // Add the plane visualization to the scene.
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let imageName = referenceImage.name ?? ""
        self.statusViewController.cancelAllScheduledMessages()
        self.statusViewController.showMessage("Detected image “\(imageName)”")
    }
}

var imageHighlightAction: SCNAction {
    return .sequence([
        .wait(duration: 0.25),
        .fadeOpacity(to: 0.85, duration: 1.50),
        .fadeOpacity(to: 0.15, duration: 1.50),
        .fadeOpacity(to: 0.85, duration: 1.50),
        .fadeOut(duration: 0.75),
        .removeFromParentNode()
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `referenceImage.name`'s value is the actual image filename.

```
if let imageName = referenceImage.name {
    plane.materials = [SCNMaterial()]
    plane.materials[0].diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```