# How to add image on ar resource of asset file

Tags: ios, arkit

I am working on image detection of **arkit**.when I am going to add image on ar resource at that time its giving me warning like this:

> Warning: Unsupported Configuration: AR reference image "" must have non-zero, positive width.

Comment: Please show some code of what you tried.

Comment: @Smartcat There is no need for code here because this is done by dragging the image to Images.xcassets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving the image in assets, you need to give the name, width, height and units of the image. You can refer this

[Xcode Error: AR reference image must have non zero positive width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757153/xcode-error-ar-reference-image-must-have-non-zero-positive-width)

[image]